# I can't get Minecraft into full screen on raspberry pi 400 OS Buster

Tags: minecraft, raspberry-pi-os-buster

When I maximize the window, the window goes full screen, but the view of the game remains the same size as the original -- although the view of the game shows that the game is in full screen because I can only see a portion of the full screen game, a portion that is the same size as the original window.

I've rebooted the game several times. I've rebooted my rpi several times. It's the raspberry pi 400 OS Buster.

I haven't yet found any solutions online. Please help me fix this!

Thank you!

Comment: I think he's saying that in full screen mode, the visible part of the game is the same size as it was before going full screen, i.e. there's a lot of black

Comment: there's [some info on raspberry pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=293973)

Comment: Thank you. So that link sent me to another link [https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/m ... h-exit-key] with instructions my terminal accepted. But the link you posted had further instructions: "Run from a terminal window inside X with
Code: Select all

minecraft-full
after the install script finishes", which I don't understand. What does "run a terminal window inside X" mean?

Comment: How do I get my terminal to open in Xcode?

Comment: what is xcode??

Comment: The link you posted says to open a terminal in Xcode to finish the install. X is an iOS code & it's not portable to Linux. But the linked post states that they're doing it.

Comment: no it doesn't ... it says open a terminal in X ... X is the windowing system, a terminal, is ... well ... a terminal `Run from a terminal window inside X with` ... and the next line has teh word `code` ... not sure where you conflated *xcode* with *X with (new line) code* - and what you run is `minecraft-full` ... in the terminal ... that you started from `X` ... `X` being linux "desktop"

Comment: @slantedview Hey, if you got your problem sorted, do you mind writing an answer to your own question explaining how you did it? That would help others who would be just as confused as you if they have  to read through the forum.

Comment: I was able to get Minecraft pi to run in full screen using the following link  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=293973  but it lags quite a bit. I still cannot get it to exit full screen, using the instructions on that page or any other instructions I've found online. If anyone has any direction for how I can exit full screen without having to reboot, I would super appreciate it. Thank You!